# Read file line by line and save one line in database row

Tags: php

I cant uderstand how to save one line in database...
I have file from web and i take him with CURL. That file look like this:

www.example.com/file.txt

> REFALIAS    http://*.example.com/data/*/*    http://example.com/data/?q=$2
>
> REFALIAS    http://*.example.com/data/*/*    http://example.com/data/?q=$2
>
> REFALIAS    http://*.example.com/data/*/*    http://example.com/data/?q=$2
>
> REFALIAS    http://*.example.com/data/*/*    http://example.com/data/?q=$2

All contnten from web i take with CURL and save in new file in my web root dir...
Now am confused with saving lines in database.

My DB shema look like this:

```
ID  |   TYPE        |   LINK_ONE                      |  LINK_TWO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  |  REFALIAS     |  http://*.example.com/data/*/*  | http://example.com/data/?q=$2
 2  |  REFALIAS     |  http://*.example.com/data/*/*  | http://example.com/data/?q=$2
 3  |  REFALIAS     |  http://*.example.com/data/*/*  | http://example.com/data/?q=$2
```

I try this:

```
<?php     
$fp = @fopen('myFile.txt', 'r');
    while(!feof($fp)) {
       $buffer = fwrite($fp, 999);
       list($type, $link_one, $link_two) = explode("\n", $buffer);
       mysql_query('INSERT INTO table ('type', 'link_one','link_two' VALUES("{$type}, {$link_one}, {$link_two}");
    }
?>
```

This back Notice: Undefined offset: 2;
I try to many examples like this and i cant save all each lines in db.
I must take line by line and save. 
I take success with only explode but how to separate all...

Any example for this

Comment: are you seriously using a fwrite to READ content from a file?

Comment: In PHP variable name start with Dollor ($),In your code your have used  query string with dollor. so php consider query string as variable and give this error. You have hide this notice using php ini display_error

Comment: $buffer = fwrite($fp, 999); What you mean by using this code in that loop?

Comment: @Harry- __don't__ suppress errors, they tell you where you've f***ed up your code

Comment: I wrote this out of my head without checking the syntax errors

Comment: @Dr.House - escape quotes in your SQL; use backticks for column names where necessary, quote string values, there's so much wrong here

Comment: The task say all error repirt must be in E_ALL... I do wrong but for that i post this. Bcs i need explain for this. And how to fix

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php     
$fp = @fopen('myFile.txt', 'r');
    while(!feof($fp)) {
       $buffer = fgets($fp);
       if (empty($buffer)) continue;
       list($type, $link_one, $link_two) = explode(" ", $buffer);
       mysql_query('INSERT INTO table (`type`, `link_one`, `link_two`) VALUES(\'' . $type . '\', \'' . $link_one . '\', \'' . $link_two . '\')');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 2;  on line --- list($type, $link_one, $link_two) = explode("\n", $buffer);

Comment: OK. I see. Your code had not only syntactical errors but it was wrong.
Your file has another format:

REFALIAS **space** http://.example.com/data// **space** http://example.com/data/?q=$2

But you use \n instead of **space** separator to explode data. And you also must use fgets instead of fread. Than you should check if fetched string is empty.

Comment: Again "Notice: Undefined offset: 2"

Comment: maybe you have tab ("\t") as separator. Can you give me a link to your file? I will check separator.

Comment: No i dont have \t, \n, &nbsp;